# How to format auto populated field in Html Span tag

Tags: html, angularjs, formatting

I have a DateOfBirth which i have formatted like below.

```
<span class="lightGreyText" >
    {{model.DateOfBirth | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}
</span>
```

i am able to achieve the date of birth in MM/dd/yyyy this format. Likewise do we anything that can format the SSN in this format (123-45-6789)
Currently my ssn format is *********

Thanks,

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: This looks like angular formatting. Perhaps you should add that tag along with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you would need to create a custom filter like the following:

```
app.filter('formatSSN', function() {
  return function(x) {
    var fSSN = '';
    fSSN += x.substr(0, 3);
    fSSN += '-' + x.substr(3, 2);
    fSSN += '-' + x.substr(5, 4);
    return fSSN;
  };
});
```

You would then be able to use this in your html like so:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="BaseController as base">
    <div>Unformatted: {{ base.ssn }}</div>
    <div>Formatted: {{ base.ssn | formatSSN }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can view the codepen example [here](http://codepen.io/amartin007/pen/XRWqed)

Comment: Works like charm.Thanks Anthony.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the accepted answer.  I wanted to add that there might be more efficient ways to do the same thing within the filter, such as a regex, and countless other ways, but I hope it helps to understand how we can create custom filters.  Cheers!